# what should comment say when programmer is aware that it is bad style but necessary

Tags: c, coding-style

In short I have code like this. I know its bad style but have given it a lot of thought and alternatives are worse. What should I say in a comment and where should I put it?

```
while(1)
{
    if(x+y == z)//some comparison
    {
        …//do something
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it should say, "it is bad style but necessary".

Comment: The code you posted could be written as `while (x + y == z) { /* do something */ }`.  I presume your real code isn't quite so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is more code involved, so the obvious

```
while(x+y == z)
{
}
```

is not possible, you could use an additional variable to flag the loop status.

```
do_loop = 1;
while (do_loop)
{
    // more code
    do_loop = (x+y == z);
    if (do_loop)
    ...
}
```

It offers more possibilities, esp. if deeper nesting is involved, since `break;` will only leave the innermost loop. Of course you should use a more exact naming for the condition instead of a generic `do_loop`, e.g. `coords_are_equal`.

If all alternatives are worse, including this, then just comment it as it is: "All alternatives are found to be worse than this."

Answer (score 0):

You might consider rewriting this as

```
while (x+y == z) {
   // Do something...
}
```